# Where are files uploaded with the Google Drive and Python API saved?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive api to upload files with a Python script.
Apparently the upload works, if I request the list of files they appear in the list.
When I log into my google drive account I can't find them anywhere.
Even if I indicate the ID of a specific folder in the metadata, I cannot find the files.

I can't understand how it works and where the files are saved. For authentication I created a service account.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'key.json'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_drive():
    """Initializes an service object.
    Returns:
    An authorized service object.
    """
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
    #creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
  # Build the service object.
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    return service


service = initialize_drive()
try:
        # Call the Drive v3 API
    file_metadata = {'name': 'img.jpg',
                     'parents': '10lqIJnK9DACpROehZJpssYjhEX0EKfPK'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('img.jpg',
                                mimetype='image/jpeg')
        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                      fields='id').execute()
    print(F'File ID: {file.get("id")}')

except HttpError as error:
    print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
    file = None


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Are they uploaded to the service account which is different from your user account?

Comment: I have create a API in google developers and I have created a service account.

Comment: Files uploaded via a service account is _owned_ by the service account itself which is considered a separate entity and is different from the user account. It may be possible for a service account to impersonate a user though. To confirm, is your user account a Google Workspace account or a personal Gmail one?

Comment: A personal Gmail account.

Comment: How I can create a JSON credential file to access with my personal account?

Comment: In this official document useful? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Domain-wide delegation and impersonation won't be possible on a service account that's created via a personal Gmail account. I suggest skipping the use of a service account altogether and authenticating via OAuth instead. You may also check this [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth.md) as well for additional info on how to implement it.

Comment: The use of OAuth open a browser page to confirm  the access...I Need to manager all using a python script on a microservice, without a browser

Comment: The only other workaround I can think of is to have the service account share the files to your Gmail account. I've posted an answer based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

### Recommendation: Have the service account share the uploaded file.

Files uploaded via a service account are owned by that service account and, by default, isn't accessible by any other user. As a workaround, you can configure your script to have the service account share the file to your Gmail account after uploading it.

Replace this part of your script:

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'img.jpg',
                 'parents': '10lqIJnK9DACpROehZJpssYjhEX0EKfPK'}
media = MediaFileUpload('img.jpg',
                            mimetype='image/jpeg')
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                  fields='id').execute()
```

With this:

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'img.jpg',
                 'parents': ['10lqIJnK9DACpROehZJpssYjhEX0EKfPK']
                 #Folder Id should be inside [] brackets
                }
media = MediaFileUpload('img.jpg',
                            mimetype='image/jpeg')
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                  fields='id').execute()
permission = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer', #This role grants the user edit permissions to the file
    'emailAddress': '*****@gmail.com',  # Replace this with your Gmail account's email address.
}
service.permissions().create(fileId=file.get("id"), body=permission, sendNotificationEmail=None).execute()
```

### Note the following:

- The files uploaded are still owned by the service account. However, your Gmail account will have edit permissions to the files.
- Files uploaded by the service account will count towards the storage limit of the service account.
- The parent folder must be shared with the service account.
- Without a specified parent folder ID in the metadata, the file uploaded and shared by the service account will show up in Google Drive's **Shared with me** page.

### Reference:

- [Drive API permission methods](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.permissions.html)

Comment: Let mek now if this works for you or if you have any questions regarding the answer I posted.

Comment: I found the right solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101592/7664722

Comment: It is similar to your answer, thanks. This solved my issue!!!